# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdaugaJobController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I want to insert data in one table and i get this error
I really don`t know why. i`m new to Laravel, please help :D

this is my route

```
Route::get('/adaugajob', 'Auth\AdaugaJobController@create')->name('adaugajob');
```

And this is my controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        if ($data) {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'titlu' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'descriere' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'salariu_estimativ' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'oras' => ['required', 'regex:^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$^'],
            ]);

        }
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if ($data) {
            Joburi::create([
                'titlu' => $data['titlu'],
                'descriere' => $data['descriere'],
                'salariu_estimativ' => $data['salariu_estimativ'],
                'oras' => $data['oras'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) You're using `create` as a get method, 2) you designed `create` so that it requires an array, but not passing in anything via the route definition. Create should be done via POST or PUT, and which point you can get the data from `$request->get()`. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing about routing and parameters

Comment: You must need one array parameter to call create method.

Comment: @PaulCatalinAgighioleanu if you resolved you're issue, you should set the right answer or add it yourself, and mark the question as resolved

Answer (score 1):

The method `Create` is expecting an array. but laravel can send only path parameter (if they exist) or the equivalent model bindings..... and always the object `Request` if requested by the function.

Change the `array $data` parameter to

```
protected function create( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    if ($data) {
        Joburi::create([
            'titlu' => $data['titlu'],
            'descriere' => $data['descriere'],
            'salariu_estimativ' => $data['salariu_estimativ'],
            'oras' => $data['oras'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

Save version:

```
protected function create( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    if ($data) {
        $joburi = new Joburi();
        $joburi->titlu = $data['titlu'];
        $joburi->descriere = $data['descriere'];
        $joburi->salariu_estimativ = $data['salariu_estimativ'];
        $joburi->oras = $data['oras'];
        $joburi->save();
        return $joburi;
    }
}
```

Comment: and if i want to save? like $data->save() it says that i call save to an array

Comment: you want to save what ? a `Joburi` instance ? why use the request to save ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This. And use store method for all insert operation.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'titlu' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'descriere' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'salariu_estimativ' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'oras'=> 'required|regex:^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$^',

    ]);

    Joburi::create([
        'titlu' => $data['titlu'],
        'descriere' => $data['descriere'],
        'salariu_estimativ' => $data['salariu_estimativ'],
        'oras' => $data['oras'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: i really have a problem with this. i changed everything and i get the "no message" error

Comment: Change your route Route::get to Route::post

Answer (score 0):

In your blade file:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'adaugajob', 'method' => 'POST')) }}

     {{-- Your input fields here --}}

     {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Create a controller in the controller folder
The code in your store function

```
public function store(Request $request){

   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'titlu' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'descriere' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'salariu_estimativ' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'oras'=> 'required|regex:^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$^',
   ]);

   if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
               ->withErrors($validator)
               ->withInput();
   }

    $post = $request->all();

    Joburi::create($post);

    return redirect('/adaugajob');
}
```

In route file (web.php):

```
Route::post('/adaugajob', 'AdaugaJobController@store')->name('adaugajob');
```